# How to return a vector of structs of a function in c++

Tags: c++, function, c++11, function-prototypes

I am trying to return a vector of structs from my class, but am getting a few errors. This is what i have setup so far:

```
class trial{

   public:
    struct coords{
      double x,y,z;
    };
    vector<coords> trial::function(vector <double> x1, vector <double> x2);
};

std:vector<coords> function(vector <double> x1, vector <double> x2){

    some math.....
    vector <coords> test;
    return test;
}
```

The error comes at the st::vector.... saying coords was not defined. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, in out-of-class definition? It should be (provided you're `using std::vector;`)

```
vector<trial::coords> trial::function(vector <double> x1, vector <double> x2){
```

In in-class declaration earlier, qualification `trial::` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

One trick you can use to avoid needing to name `trial::coords` fully in the return type is a trailing return value:

```
// still need the first `trial::`, but the one on `coords` is inferred
auto trial::function(vector <double> x1, vector <double> x2) -> vector<coords> {
    ...
}
```